# How to load grub modules forbidden by secure boot?

Tags: grub2, secure-boot

I have a multi-boot system with secure boot enabled that's working just fine except for one thing. I have a custom.cfg which uses the datehook module to determine which OS to boot into, and after enabling secure boot this module can no longer load. When trying to load the module it says that secure boot forbids loading it.

Other than that secure boot is working fine for all my OSes so I would rather not have to start over or regenerate any keys. How can I get this module to work again with secure boot enabled?

This is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You have not stated what version of Ubuntu you are using.